# Why does `will end` behave differently than `will leave` in program-level scope?

Tags: raku

I thought that in the top level of a program that `will end` and `will leave` would behave the same way, since there is only one big outer scope to exit/leave from. I thought that either one would be a good way to check a variable's final value.

But with `will end` it acts like the variable has never been initialized:

```
my $foo will end { put "Final value for \$foo is '$_'"} = 'bar';

put "\$foo is now '$foo'";

$foo ~= ' baz';
```

OUTPUT

> ```
> $foo is now 'bar'
> Use of uninitialized value $_ of type Any in string context.
> Methods .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something meaningful.
>   in block  at phaser_end.p6 line 1
> Final value for $foo is ''
> ```

However, simply changing `will end` to `will leave` does what I would expect from either one:

```
my $foo will leave { put "Final value for \$foo is '$_'"} = 'bar';

put "\$foo is now '$foo'";

$foo ~= ' baz';
```

OUTPUT

> ```
> $foo is now 'bar'
> Final value for $foo is 'bar baz'
> ```

Why is there a difference in behavior here?

I am using Rakudo-Star 2017.07.

### UPDATE

To get the effect that I'm expecting with `will end`, I have to use a separate `END` block:

`END` block:

```
my $foo = 'bar';

END { put "Final value for \$foo is '$foo'"};

put "\$foo is now '$foo'";

$foo ~= ' baz';
```

I guess the real question boils down to why does the `END` block behave differently than the `will end` block.

`will end` block:

```
my $foo will end { put "Final value for \$foo is '$_'"} = 'bar';

put "\$foo is now '$foo'";

$foo ~= ' baz';
```

Comment: @raiph Is the scope for the block with `will end` different than the scope of the block with `will leave`?

Comment: @raiph I would definitely welcome additional explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rewritten**

> Why does `will end` behave differently than `will leave`

It looks like `will end` has a bug similar to [this old and now resolved bug for `will begin`](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=119109).

Other than that, everything works as I would expect:

```
my $leave will leave { say ['leave:', $_, OUTERS::<$leave>] } = 'leave';
my $end   will end   { say ['end:',   $_, OUTERS::<$end>]   } = 'end';
my $begin will begin { say ['begin:', $_, OUTERS::<$begin>] } = 'begin';
               END   { say ['END:',   $_, OUTERS::<$end>, $end] }

$_ = 999;
```

displays

```
[begin: (Any) (Any)]
[leave: leave leave]
[END: 999 end end]
[end: 999 end]
```

> Is the scope for the block with `will end` different than the scope of the block with `will leave`?

They have the same outer [*lexical* scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping) that corresponds to the `UNIT` scope.

They run in different [*dynamic* scopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping). Leave blocks run as part of leaving the enclosing block. End blocks run [after the compiler has completely finished with your code and is cleaning up](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/1adacc72cb7b123b716e89f6eb2c9fecc615a756/src/main.nqp#L43):

```
sub MAIN(@ARGS) {
    ...
    # UNIT scope -- your code -- is about to be created and compiled:
    $comp.command_line ...
    # UNIT scope no longer exists. We compiled it, ran it, and left it.
    ...
    # do all the necessary actions at the end, if any
    if nqp::gethllsym('perl6', '&THE_END') -> $THE_END {
        $THE_END()
    }
}
```

> why does the `END` block behave differently than the `will end` block?

Because you used `$foo` in one and `$_` in the other.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use `OUTERS::<$end>` for `will end` blocks until the bug is fixed. I just need to work up a bug report now.